# c# button onclick ask for user input

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone-8

I have a button,

```
<Button x:Name="myButton"
     Content="Click Me!"
     Click="myButton_Click" />
```

When I press the button, I want to ask the user to enter a number,

```
private void myButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        int i = numberUserEnters;
        //do something with i
    }
```

how do I have the on screen keyboard appear on a button press?

Comment: if you do not want to use `Java Script` have you looked into using `Microsoft.VisualBasic` NameSpace`? C# does not have this function out the box but VB.NET Does and you can use that inside of C# I've done this many times before please show more effort as well i.e `Google search`[Google.com](http://www.google.com)

Comment: Do you want the textbox to be visible along with the keyboard or just the keyboard?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can have User input from `UserControl`. try this :

XAML :

```
    <Popup VerticalAlignment="Center" x:Name="MyPopup">
        <StackPanel Width="480">
            <TextBox x:Name="txtdata"></TextBox>
            <Button Content="Ok" x:Name="btnOk" Click="btnOk_Click"></Button>
            <Button Content="Cancel" x:Name="btnCancel" Click="btnCancel_Click"></Button>
        </StackPanel>
    </Popup>
```

CS:

```
private void btnOk_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    if (txtdata.Text != "")
    {
        MyPopup.IsOpen = false;
        LayoutRoot.Opacity = 1.0;
        MessageBox.Show(txtdata.Text);
    }
}

private void btnCancel_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    MyPopup.IsOpen = false;
    LayoutRoot.Opacity = 1.0;
}

private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    MyPopup.IsOpen = true;
    LayoutRoot.Opacity = 0.5;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You will need to navigate to a new, separate page which contains the TextBox where you will capture the user's input.  The page will also need OK and Cancel buttons to allow the user to confirm, then you could return control back to the previous page.

If you look at existing Windows Phone apps they tend to work this way.

Answer (score 0):

There is a number of ways to do this.

The easiest way would be to use the [Telerik Rad Controls, Rad Message Box](http://www.telerik.com/products/windows-phone/overview/all-controls/messagebox.aspx)

However, if you don't want to pony up for the controls you can build your own and display it.

I would look into how to create a [User Control On Windows Phone](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/ff402561%28v=vs.105%29.aspx) and how to display them.

It is much easier then you think.

Answer (score 0):

As Anthony Russell suggested, RadControls would be a good approach but if you don't have them or don't want to pay for them,  [Coding4Fun Toolkit's InputPrompt](http://www.geekchamp.com/articles/wp7-inputprompt-in-depth) is free and quite flexible.